# ImageResizer Polymorphic/Set Source in Pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I'm trying to drop in ImageResizer to replace an existing system on an ASP.NET MVC site. Currently the site supports two similar URLs:

```
"/images/[GUID]"
```

and

```
"/images/$[GUID]"
```

These point to two different data sources. Currently one of these looks for the image data in an otherwise inaccessible folder while the other looks in a SQL database. Is there a way to dynamically change the source for the image data in the pipeline (to different folder or to the SQL provider)? By adding an event to the current pipeline's `PostAuthorizeRequestStart` I've been able to change some of the behavior, but I'm not sure how to alter the actual data source. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this using the Rewrite event handler and rewriting the prefix to match my source. Not sure if this is the best way, but it is working.